# Youtube slower on my site than on Youtube

Tags: performance, youtube, external

I have several YouTube videos embedded on my website. I'm using the Jquery youtubeplaylist.js to load and play the movies. I recently noticed that the videos on my website stall and stutter occasionally. If I watch the same videos directly through YouTube then the videos load quickly and play smoothly.

Could it be the youtubeplaylist script that is causing the slow down? Or, could it be the fact that I am loading the video in at a custom size?

Also, does YouTube give preference to the videos played directly on their site?

Comment: Yes, this is on a shared hosting account.

Comment: Here's my 2 cents about this: shared hostings are usually slower than VPS or Dedicated because they share all the resources with other websites (memory, processor, bandwidth etc...) So if on your account you are with 100 other sites that takes 90% of the bandwidth you will have latency issues. Now youtube have tons of servers and cache servers which is why it will never be slow.

Comment: Shouldn't the videos get served equally fast since they are streaming from YouTube via an iFrame? Or maybe I don't fully understand the way YouTube videos stream through 3rd party sites.

Comment: make sure you are using iframe version of the embed so it will be faster than the FLASH version (object)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same problem, but there are too many variables to know for sure. It's clear that the nocookie player that loads from youtube-nocookie loads much slower than the regular player. Google has likely devoted fewer resources to this version of the player, probably because it garners less revenue to make up for the cost of serving video. Using the regular player, things do appear to be slower at times outside of YouTube, but that could be purely coincidental.

Having shared hosting or not shouldn't matter, since as you note the video stream is directly between Google's servers and the user's browser.